# I am enclosed by rock and ice - What am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am completely enclosed by rock and ice. I see no light of day. No human has ever been here, but if you could come here then you wouldn't know what time of day it is. What am I?

Comment: cold? freezing?

Comment: It seems to me a lot of answers would fit this - a frozen mammoth, the middle of an asteroid, a Nazi UFO buried in Antarctica,...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you might be

> Lake Vostok, a large lake of liquid water beneath the ice at Russia's Vostok Station.

I am completely enclosed by rock and ice.

> The lake has ice above it and rock below it.

I see no light of day.

> The ice is thick enough, ~4000 m, that no light can get through it - so it is always in total darkness.

No human has ever been here,

> obviously (although a probe has been sent down through the ice to collect a water sample).

but if you could come here then you wouldn't know what time of day it is.

> presumably because there are no official time zones in Antarctica. Note though that it isn't exactly below the south pole so in principle you could argue that there is a 'local time' based on its longitude of 106 E

Comment: Correct! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Woah - and that just got me past 1k rep...

Comment: @Penguino Congratulations on your 1k rep, Penguino! I hope you reach 10K soon.

Answer (score 10):

Are you:

> A [comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet).

As Wikipedia says:

> [Comets are] .. collections of ice, dust, and small rocky particles

and:

> because they don't orbit the sun in a circular orbit, the concept of night and day is irrelevant to them.

And:

> No human has ever been to a comet.

Comment: The orbit of earth it also irrelevant to determine whether it's day or night although earth's orbit is nearly circular. The rotation around its own axis is what brings day and night to earth, so this might as well happen to a comet.

Answer (score 8):

Could you be

> the north pole? specifically in the ocean at the north pole?

I am stuck between rock and ice

> under the ice and above the rock is the artic ocean

I see no light of day.

> under the ice and snow is dark, not to mention in the winter, no sunlight above the ice either

If you come here then you won't know what time of day it is.

> at the north pole all of the time zones converge, so how would you know what time it is?

Comment: oooh you are very close. I've modified the wording to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 7):

It could very well be

> The South pole

Reasoning

> The South Pole i.e Antarctica is ice capped throughout the year and moreover, the words "Rock and Ice" clearly show the existence of a continent.

And also

> The longitudes diverge from the south pole thus at the south pole there is no notion of time.

Comment: also very close. But please note the "completely enclosed" part. This means that the object in question does not touch any objects other than rock and ice.

Comment: it can be taken that the true South Pole is actually at ground level, not on the ice above.  So, it would be enclosed in ice and rock.

Comment: @Jim exactly, that's what I was saying

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to @SteveV answer, but it is the opposite seeing as the OP said they were were so close.

Are you:

> Antartica?

I am stuck between rock and ice

> Antarctica is very mountainous, and it is a lot of large, rocky islands all meshed together by a *continent's* worth of ice

I see no light of day.

> Antarctica only sees sunlight for half of the year: it is shrouded in complete darkness for the rest. Sunlight doesn't get very far through the ice.

If you come here then you won't know what time of day it is.

> There are no official time zones for Antarctica. Bases either go by the time of their home country or that of the nearest civilized place.

Comment: That is exactly what I answered 5 minutes ago

Comment: In my answer I have explicitly mentioned Antarctica and moreover, since the south pole lies in Antarctica it is fit to say that by referring to the south pole you are referring to the landmass of Antarctica

Answer (score 2):

Is it,

> Northern pole of inaccessibility

As

> Also known as Arctic pole of inaccessibility is under the ice and above the rock, with no sunlight and convergence of time zone.

Also, according to Wikipedia,

> Due to constant motion of the pack ice, no permanent structure can exist at this pole. Making it unable to reach.